# Create a label or other control based on database table value

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I want  to create a label or textbox based on database column value..
For example:
            I have a database table column value Casual Leave,Medical Leave,Annual leave,etc..  I want to create dynamic label and corresponding textbox for the above column value.

I want the control like this..

```
         Casual Leave :  Textbox1
         Medical Leave:  Textbox2
         Annul Leave  :  Textbox3
         etc based on table value
```

what i do? I can't do this. please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using an ASP repeater. Really simple. You define a template of controls which will be used to create the dynamic instances (or rows in your case) when bound to the data source.

Comment: Thanks for ur kind reply. could u send any example page.

Comment: Here you go... http://www.netrostar.com/Tutorials-91-ASP.NET%20Tutorial.%20How%20to%20use%20Repeater - how you format the item template and what/how you bind your data to the repeater will obviously differ.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<asp:Panel Id="pnl" runat ="server">
    </asp:Panel>


Label lblT = null;
            TextBox txt = null;
            Table tb = new Table();
            pnl.Controls.Add(tb);
            DataTable table = DT_GeneratedOp();
            foreach (DataColumn dr in table.Columns)
            {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                TableCell tc2 = new TableCell();
                lblT = new Label();
                txt = new TextBox();
                lblT.Text = dr.ColumnName + ":";
                txt.Text = table.Rows[0][dr].ToString();
                tc.Controls.Add(lblT);
                tc2.Controls.Add(txt);
                tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                tr.Cells.Add(tc2);
                tb.Rows.Add(tr);
            }
```